# How to arrange animation order properly in Swift language for ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to realize the effect like this: move a pile of cards(UIView) from (0,0) to (100,100) one by one; after the last card finishes moving, all of cards begin move back to (0,0) one by one. I wrote the code like below, but the effect is not correct. Please help me to figure it out where is the problem.

```
import UIKit
class Card:UIView{
    var name: String = ""
    init(name: String){
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.name = name
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cardGroup : Card[] = []
    @IBOutlet var startPressed: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
    }

    @IBAction func start(){
        var cardOrder = [ "HeartSix", "HeartSeven", "HeartEight","HeartNine", "HeartTen", "DiamondJack", "ClubQueen", "SpadeKing","HeartAce" ]
        for (var i = 0;  i < cardOrder.count ; ++i){
            var card = Card(name: cardOrder[i])
            cardGroup.append(card)
            self.view.addSubview(cardGroup[i])
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.cardGroup[i].center = CGPoint(x: 100 + 3*i, y: 100 + 3*i)                
            }  , completion:{
                (Bool) -> Void in
                //sound.stop()
            })
        }
        self.nextAnimation()                
}

    func nextAnimation(){
        for (var i = 0;  i < cardGroup.count ; ++i){
             UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.cardGroup[i].center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)               
            }  , completion:{
                (Bool) -> Void in
                //sound.stop()
            })
        }        
     }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `self.nextAnimation()` in completion handler

```
 @IBAction func start(){
        var cardOrder = [ "HeartSix", "HeartSeven", "HeartEight","HeartNine", "HeartTen", "DiamondJack", "ClubQueen", "SpadeKing","HeartAce" ]
        for (var i = 0;  i < cardOrder.count ; ++i){
            var card = Card(name: cardOrder[i])
            cardGroup.append(card)
            self.view.addSubview(cardGroup[i])
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.cardGroup[i].center = CGPoint(x: 100 + 3*i, y: 100 + 3*i)                
            }  , completion:{
                (Bool) -> Void in
                //sound.stop()
              self.nextAnimation()                
            })
        }

}
```

Comment: It works, but can you explain why? You put nextAnimation() func in for loop, and does it mean the program will run this function cardOrder.count times?

Comment: I add a println() in nextAnimation() func  and it shows this function runs several times, which is not expected. I want to run it only one time with expected effect. Could you figure it out?